# How to compare argv and another string?

Tags: c

It's like my code doesn't compare the two. I don't understand why. It's the first if condition that gives me trouble. How can I do to solve the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen(argv[1], "rw");
    char s1[30], s2[30], s3[30];

    if(strcmp(argv[2], "new") == 0){
        while(fscanf(in, "%s %s %s", s1,s2,s3) == 3){
            if(strcmp(s1, argv[3]) == 0 && strcmp(s2,argv[4])==0 && strcmp(s3, argv[5])==0){
                printf("Errore! Cartolina già esistente.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        fprintf(in, "%s %s %s\n", argv[3], argv[4], argv[5]);
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[2], "find") == 0){
        while(fgets(s1, 30, in) != NULL){
            if(strstr(s1, argv[3]) != NULL){
                printf("%s", s1);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;


}
```

EDIT: I just realized that I used "r" instead of "rw" but it still doesn't print argv[3], argv[4] and argv[5] in the file.

Comment: How do you invoke it?

Comment: How do you execute your code? Are you sure the first if's condition is not satisfied? That condition seems fine.

Comment: Soo..? Is your edit changing anything in the question?

Comment: @EugeneSh. it finds if there are equal arguments but if there aren't it doesn't print them in the file.

Comment: did you see what the first two comments are asking for? Also the contents of the input file are needed

Comment: @EugeneSh. ./prog file.txt new laura anna milano

Comment: @EugeneSh. no, it's ./prog file.txt new laura anna milano

Comment: Well, time to use a debugger.

Comment: How do you call your program? What is the file's content?

Comment: @WernerHenze I call it with ./prog file.txt new laura anna milano and the file contains three strings on each line. If one line contains the three strings I passed, it doesn't print it in the file, otherwise it should print it.

Comment: Just realized that the `fopen` mode is not appropriate.. but there is already an answer about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not opening the file correctly:

```
in = fopen(argv[1], "rw");
```

`rw` is not a valid mode.  If you want to open for reading and writing, use `r+` instead.  Also, don't forget to check if `fopen` failed.

```
in = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
if (!in) {
    perror("fopen failed");
    exit(1);
 }
```

Comment: Does fprintf always automatically print at the end of the file?

Comment: `"w+"` might better suit the questioners needs. BTW, your new code still shows `"rw"`.

Comment: @WernerHenze `w+` isn't appropriate here because it truncates the file.

Comment: @user11006304 It will print wherever the file pointer happens to be.  In your case, you start reading at the beginning and continue until the end, so it prints at the end.

Comment: @dbush Good point. `"a+"` would be the mode that creates the file if it not exists.